# Plot Cumulative Returns of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas time-series dataframe:

```
                  q1        q2        q3        q4        q5
2001-09-30  0.211770  0.085683  0.050699  0.037150  0.042206
2001-10-31  0.203492  0.107347  0.075474  0.063460  0.052081
2001-11-30  0.089562  0.064950  0.055432  0.058544  0.052215
2001-12-31 -0.078566 -0.017314 -0.015337  0.003871  0.013463
2002-01-31 -0.151178 -0.024362 -0.012938 -0.005622 -0.010209
```

What's the most elegant way of computing cumulative returns of each bucket and then plot a line chart?

For example, cumulative return of 'q1' at 2001-11-30 is calculated as:

```
(1+0.211770) x (1+0.203492) x (1+0.089562) - 1 = 0.588969
```

And the final line chart should look something like this (I don't really care about the aesthetics of the chart, e.g., font, date format, legend location, etc.):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add 1, then use `cumprod()`, subtract 1 and then `plot()`.

```
((df + 1).cumprod() - 1).plot()
```

Comment: Just q quick follow-up: how to add title to that chart?

Comment: `plot(title='Hello World')` [see the doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)